# Dynamic hyperlink handling different extensions

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I want to create a dynamic hyperlink that opens variable extensions.

This is the formula that I use for creating the hyperlink:

```
+HYPERLINK("location"&filename&".pdf",friendlyname)
```

With this formula, I can open .pdf files, but no files with other file extensions. I would like to open files with .jpeg extensions and other the same way. How could I do this?

I would like to stick with generating the hyperlink by a formula (instead of generating it by macro / VBA code).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of opening a **folder** with a hyperlink formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("file:///C:\TestFolder","a folder")
```

Clicking this link will open an explorer window. Double-clicking a file in the explorer window will open that file:

[image]

**Note:**

No macros are involved! *(you must build a string similar to my example)*

**EDIT#1:**

Here is an example of opening a specific file:

```
=HYPERLINK("file:///C:\TestFolder\x.jpg","an image file")
```

Comment: Thank you, but it will open the folder but not the exact file that I linked.

Comment: @arkhe  If this is of no value to you, I will delete the Answer.

Comment: @arkhe  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply but this is not the case how I want.

Comment: Now it will open only jpeg file, instead, there should be something that opens all. Maybe something like "*" but it doesn't work for the hyperlink.

Comment: @arkhe  I understand your question now *(I think)*; I don't know how to make a hyperlink that opens more than one file.

Comment: Sorry for miss understanding, I wrote "opens all" but correctly should be "opens required extension".